# How to get the size of "_cl_devide_id" struct in openCL?

Tags: parallel-processing, gpu, opencl

cl_device_id is defined as "typedef struct _cl_device_id *cl_device_id".
In the openCL method clGetDeviceIDs, "devices" parameter is of the type "cl_device_id *" and returns a pointer to the list of devices available. I'm trying to pass the whole struct using memcpy to another variable. For which I need to know the size of the "_cl_device_id" struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*_cl_device_id* is internal to the platform (like all *_cl_something* structs). Furthermore, an OpenCL program can have multiple platforms loaded, and for each platform the struct sizes can (and likely will) be different.

All *cl_objects* in general are opaque pointers, and (in general) copying around hidden internal structs of a C library is a pretty extreme approach, almost guaranteed to screw things up (unless you're working on implementing a debugger or such).

But anyway leaving motivation aside, the answer is: you can't tell, since you don't know until the program actually runs and loads the OpenCL implementation(s).

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. I was working on a custom runtime which sits between the opencl application and actual opencl runtime. I'm intercepting the function calls from the original application, sending the parameters to my runtime, calling the same function from my runtime(with the previously fetched parameters), which would now interact with the actual opencl runtime. The actual opencl runtime would send back some function return calls like CE_SUCCESS or in the above case, the list of devices available. I need to pass them back to the original opencl application.

Comment: That's why I needed to know the size of _cl_device_id struct, so that I could copy the whole structure with memcpy