# How do I obtain the numeric device ID of a cl::Device?

Tags: c++, opencl

The OpenCL C++ bindings has the `cl::Device` class wrapping a `_cl_device_id *`. The pointed-to type is opaque to us.

How can one obtain, given a `cl::Device`, its numeric ID (within its context)? The base-class' `operator()` only gives me the wrapped `_cl_device_id *`, not a number.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65665272/9178992), `_cl_device_id` cannot practically be used to get a unique device ID. Instead, to assign unique IDs to all available divices use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57336786/9178992).

Comment: The fact that the opaque struct cannot be used programmatically is a tautology. However, the `cl::Device` definitely has a numeric ID - when it was obtained via an enumeration (`context.getInfo<CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES>()`). Also, I don't care about multiple platforms and contexts, just the one.

Answer (score 0):

If you also have access to your context (i.e. you hold `my_device` and `my_context`), here's an ugly, expensive hack for you:

```
std::vector<cl::Device> devices = my_context.getInfo<CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES>();
auto it = std::find(devices.begin(), devices.end(), my_device);
auto device_index = std::distance (devices.begin(), it);
```

... but I would really rather avoid this.